# Flutter - How create Container with width match parent?

Tags: flutter, dart

I use this simple widget in my Flutter app:

```
  FlatButton(
   child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset(assets, height: 40, width: 40),
            Text('Title'),
            //my color line
            Container(
              height: 5,
              width: ?,
              color: Colors.blue[800],
            )
          ],
        )
  )
```

I need color line (in buttom), with width match parent. but I don’t know how to do it.

Comment: Did you try to set it as double.infinity?

Comment: You want the blue line as big as the image? or a line a width as the button? If it is the case, just remove the width param

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use [IntrinsicWidth](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicWidth-class.html)

```
 FlatButton(
   child: IntrinsicWidth(
   child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset(assets, height: 40, width: 40),
            Text('Title'),
            //my color line
            Container(
              height: 5,
              width: ?,
              color: Colors.blue[800],
            )
          ],
        ))
  )
```

[Some cheatsheet](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-layout-cheat-sheet-5363348d037e)

Answer (score 71):

```
Container(
    height: 5,
    width: double.infinity,
    color: Colors.blue[800],
)
```

Comment: Is there something against this answer? I like its simplicity.

Comment: This answer does not wrong that is the bad thing. I tested it want to create a container with only shape and fills size but this doesn't

Answer (score 17):

Two ways of doing this

**ConstrainedBox:**

It Creates a widget that imposes additional constraints on its child, which internally uses `SingleChildRenderObjectWidget` to add constraints over the child widget.

```
ConstrainedBox(
        constraints:
            const BoxConstraints(minWidth: double.infinity, maxHeight: 10),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
```

**SizedBox:**

SizedBox simply creates a box with a given width/height and doesn't allow the child to go beyond given dimensions. It also used `SingleChildRenderObjectWidget` to decide the child render area

```
SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 5,
        // height: double.infinity,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 3):

`Container` in a `Column` with no child will always expand. if you do add a `child` it will wrap it.

Also if you don't constrain your `Column` in the button it will also grow to full available height.

My suggestion to you is instead of putting an empty `Container` in your button's Column, rather wrap the button with a Container and give it a bottom border. This will give you your colored line on the bottom.

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border(
      bottom: BorderSide(width: 5, color: Colors.blue[800]),
    ),
  ),
  child: FlatButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, // prevent Column to expand full height
      children: <Widget>[
        Icon(Icons.cake, size: 40),
        Text('title'),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```